# Why do we write $H_0^1(\Omega) \cap H^2$ instead of only $H^2_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, weak-derivatives, poissons-equation

I've seen that when we deal with Poisson equation with homogeneous boundary conditions, let's say in 2D with a convex domain $\Omega$, we write that the regularity of $u$ is $H^2 \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$. Why can't we just say that it is in $H^2_0(\Omega)$?

Does it have to do with trace theorem?

Comment: It is a matter of notation: $H^2\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$ is unambiguous, whereas $H^k_0(\Omega)$ may mean `functions in $H^k(\Omega)$ with derivatives vanishing on $\partial\Omega$ up to the maximal order' for which this makes sense (which depends on the dimension of the ambient Euclidean space). In general, subscripts tend to refer to the totality of possible conditions. For instance: $\mathcal C^\infty_b(\mathbb R^n)$ is the space of smooth functions that are bounded and have bounded derivatives of all orders, not just the space $\mathcal C^\infty\cap \mathcal C_b$.

Comment: But, as far as I know, in $H^2_0$ we have 0 (in the sense of traces) normal derivatives on the boundary... while in $H^1_0 \cap H^2$ we don't have 0 normal derivatives a priori. So I'd say that $H_0^1 \cap H^2 \ne H_0^2$, right? @AlephBeth

Comment: Again this depends on the notation one is used to. If your definition of $H^2_0$ is `functions with vanishing normal derivative on $\partial \Omega$', then yes: $H^1_0\cap H^2\neq H^2_0$. However, if you think of solutions of the homogeneous Poisson equation (to fix the ideas, consider the homogeneous Laplace equation on the unit interval, which is a special case) it does not make much sense to look for solutions in $H^2_0$.

Comment: Why do you say that it doesn't make sense to look for $H^2_0$ solutions? @AlephBeth

Comment: Sorry! Laplace was of course too strict... my point was simply that if we are looking at the Poisson equation $u''=f$ on $[0,1]$ and by homogeneous boundary conditions we only mean $u(0)=u(1)=0$, then (for suitable $f$'s) there exist solutions for which $u'(0)\neq 0$ (so $u\notin H^2_0$).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the equation
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u =2 &  \text{ in } B_1,\\
\quad \, u=0 & \text{ on }\partial B_1,
\end{cases}
$$
where $B_1$ denotes the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geq 1$. Then the function $u(x)= 1-|x|^2$ is a solution. You can check directly that $u\in H^1_0(B_1)\cap H^2(B_1)$ (or nuke flies and appeal to the regularity theory), but $u\notin H^2_0(B_1)$ since the gradient $\nabla u(x) = -2x$ is not in $H^1_0(B_1)$.